# Sorting a list of strings by date using Python and strptime

Tags: python, datetime

I have a series of strings that are structured as follows:

```
01.06.2012 09:45 a a a
01.06.2012 08:00 b b b
21.12.2012 21:00 c c c
13.07.2011 17:00 d d d
26.05.2012 08:00 e e e
```

Each string starts with a date and time, formatted as `dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm`, followed by additional data. I want to sort these strings by date and time in ascending order.

I'm aware that Python's `strptime` function could help me convert the date string into a `datetime` object, but I'm not sure about the best way to utilize it for this task.

Could someone demonstrate how to use `strptime` to sort this list of strings by date and time?

The strings are read from the console (standard input). Thank you!

Comment: You already know the solution, so what you're effectively looking for is someone to *give you teh codez?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import datetime

a_list = ["01.06.2012 09:45 a a a", "01.06.2012 08:00 b b b", "21.12.2012 21:00 c c c", "13.07.2011 17:00 d d d", "26.05.2012 08:00 e e e"]

def sorting(x):
    date = " ".join(x.split()[:2])
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')

print sorted(a_list, key=sorting)
```

This code just use a custom sort function to split the string, get only the part that has the date, and then parse it using strptime.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could just use `sort()`.

```
listLength = input()
timeList = []
while listLength:
    timeStr = raw_input()
    timeList.append(timeStr)
    listLength = listLength - 1

timeList.sort()
print '-' * 10
for timeStr in timeList:
    print timeStr
```